# Flutter sdk version not recognized

Tags: windows, dart, flutter

I just installed flutter version 2.0.6(latest) on my system and when I tried to see the version in the terminal it showed me 2.0.6 which is no surprise but after using it for some days I kept seeing some other version in my editor(shown below). When I tried running `flutter --version` it showed me something like this given below. I am kind of confused is it some new version or format or something else.

```
Flutter 2.3.0-1.0.pre.204 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 741bb9d329 (2 days ago) • 2021-05-02 01:29:03 -0300
Engine • revision 3e578c6e0d
Tools • Dart 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-48.0.dev)
```

Comment: What is wrong with this output? You are using the Master channel and it is currently on version: `2.3.0-1.0.pre.204`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you changed your channel without noticing.
Run this

`flutter channel stable`

Then flutter version will be set to 2.0.6

Here's flutter sdk release version info
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases